# Why does 7z create different files?

Tags: bash, 7zip, md5sum

I'm using 7z command in bash script to create a 7z archive for backup purposes. My script does also check if this newly created 7z archive exists in my backup folder and if it does, I go and run md5sum to see if content differs. So if the archive file doesn't exits yet or the md5sum differs from the previous I copy it to my backup folder. So I tried a simple example to test the script, but the problem is that I sometimes get different md5sum for the same folder I am compressing. Why is that so? Is there any other reliable way of checking if file content differs? The commands are simple:

```
SourceFolder="/home/user/Documents/"
for file in $SourceFolder*
do
  localfile=${file##*/}
  7z a -t7z "$SourceFolder${localfile}.7z" "$file"
  md5value=`md5sum "$SourceFolder${localfile}.7z"|cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

...copyinf files goes from here on...

Comment: Is this a linux emulator running under windows? If so, windows is probably modifying the contents of `Documents` in some manner so as to cause md5sum to return a different checksum.

Comment: Please use the `fullcode` markup and not the `\``

Comment: Maybe 7z includes a time stamp (creation time stamp?) in the archive. Compare them with `cmp -l 1.7z 2.7z` and see how many bytes are different.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I meant `code sample`. I speak wrong english when I run with low levels of caffeine

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the code sample with four spaces, not the one with double `\``. This sounds better ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The toolbar button that formats the selection as code (by applying the indent) really is named "Code Sample".

Comment: Can you provide a source file and the two (different) 7z archives that get created for it?

Comment: ah, formatting... sorry, I though he was talking about the code...

Comment: I am doing all this inside a virtual machine Ubuntu 12.04 hosted on Windows 8 with VirtualBox,but the host does not have any access to the folder I'm compressing. I don't know what 7z adds, it may be some kind of time stamp, I'll try to use cmp to get the differences. I'll try to create a sample source file and the resulting differing archives, I can not publish the original ones, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The reliable way to check if two different losslessly compressed files have identical contents is to expand their contents and compare those (e.g. using md5sum).  Comparing the compressed files is going to end badly sooner or later, regardless of which compression scheme you use.

Comment: I agree, but with 7z I'm compressing entire folders and it doesn't sound handy to compare their files in entire tree structure. Maybe I could do that somehow, recursively, but how no I idea how to, yet. Can I use some other equivalent for getting same result? Can I create tar archives without compression and compare md5sum of them with the md5sum of old backup tars, would that work? Does tar always create a file with same md5sum (suppose I'm archiving same content and don't use the "z" switch)?

Comment: @arcull: `tar` is worth trying, sure.  It's a lot less likely to change over time, and a quick test on my system shows that tarring the same directory twice gives the same `md5sum` on both tar output files.  Give it a try.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I've partially  solved this. It looks like it matters if you specify full path to the folder you are compressing or not. The resulting file is not the same. .This affects both 7z and tar.I mean like this:

`value1=$(tar -c /tmp/at-spi2/|md5sum|cut -d ' ' -f 1)
value2=$(tar -c at-spi2/|md5sum|cut -d ' ' -f 1)`

So obviously I'm doing this wrong. Is there a switch for 7z and tar which would remove absolute path?